# Integrating Data

Tags: r, merge

I have a large data frame as follows which is a subset of a larger data frame.

```
tree=data.frame(INVYR=tree$INVYR,
            DIA=tree$DIA,PLOT=tree$PLOT,SPCD=tree$SPCD,
            D.2=tree$D.2, BA.T=tree$BA.T)
```

What I am attempting to do is calculate the total BA.T per Plot per Year (plots are remeasured in subsequent years). I do this by ...

```
x<-aggregate(tree$BA.T,list(tree$INVYR,tree$PLOT),FUN=sum)

x$PLOT<-x$Group.2

x<- x[with(x, order(Group.1,Group.2)), ]
```

This gives me the data frame...

```
x=data.frame(Group.1,Group.2,x,PLOT)
```

Where Group.1 is the INVYR, Group.2 is the PLOT, and x is total BA.T per plot per year. So far this works great. Here is where my problem begins. I then want to integrate this back into my original tree data.frame. If I merge the data by plot it doesn't account for year and quadrupoles the data set because of the four remeasurements. I can't run an if statement because the data set is not equal lengths. The data.frame I wish to accompolish is

```
tree=data.frame(INVYR, DIA, PLOT, SPCD, D.2, BA.T, x)
```

where x is the total BA.T for the given  INVYR and PLOT of that record.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Edit

```
INVYR=rbind(1982,1982,1982,1982,1982,1995,1995,1995,1995,1995,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000)
PLOT=rbind(1,1,2,2,3,1,1,2,2,3,1,1,2,2,3)
BA.T=rbind(.1,.2,.3,.4,.2,.3,.5,.8,.3,.6,.7,.2,.1,1,1.02)
tree=data.frame(INVYR,PLOT,BA.T)
head(tree)
x<-aggregate(tree$BA.T,list(tree$INVYR,tree$PLOT),FUN=sum)
x$PLOT<-x$Group.2
x$INVYR<-x$Group.1
x<- x[with(x, order(Group.1,Group.2)), ]
head(x)
```

Comment: Hard to understand without proper example data

Answer (score 0):

On solution is to use package `reshape2`.

```
library(reshape2)
melt(data=tree,id.vars=c('INVYR','PLOT')) ## Notice the choice of the id!the keys!
 dcast(tree.m,formula=...~variable,fun.aggregate=sum)
  INVYR PLOT BA.T
1  1982    1 0.30
2  1982    2 0.70
3  1982    3 0.20
4  1995    1 0.80
5  1995    2 1.10
6  1995    3 0.60
7  2000    1 0.90
8  2000    2 1.10
9  2000    3 1.02
```